# When will the derivative of an absolutely continuous function become Riemann-integrable?

Tags: calculus, riemann-integration, absolute-continuity

By the fundamental theorem of calculus, we know that the derivative of an absolutely continuous function is Lebesgue-integrable. But my confusion is : when will it become Riemann-integrable? Should we add some conditions like monotonic?

Comment: A function is Riemann integrable if and only if it is bounded and continuous almost everywhere. That doesn't really answer your question, but might be helpful.

Comment: $f(x) = \sqrt{|x|}$ is absolutely continuous but the derivative is not Riemann integrable.